# Customize the Refinement Panel

Tags: sharepoint-search, refinement-panel

I have added the Refinement Panel webpart to the searchresult page. I have added the custom refiners to the webpart. I have a large set of items in the refiner. Can I open a div having all the refiners while clicking the "Show More" link below the refiners?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated html structure. The long list div 'unselLongList' is already there but hidden, The 'Show More' link toggles show or hide. Use the web part property to edit the number of Refiners to show. Keep it higher number for your refiner.